# How to get Date diffrence in hh:mm format In Select Query Sql 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

I am  trying to get the the result of in time and out time from dates 
but it returns only hours using following select Query as follows

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Hh,InTime,OutTime)  as Diff_time from EmpLogTable
```

and i need result in HH:MM 
Suppose  my in time is 11 am and out is 5.49pm so o/p would be 6.49 but 
using above select query i am getting o/p as 7 only 
if any body has a solution then please let me know

Thanking you in Advance 
Umesh Rakhe

Answer (score 1):

The `DATEDIFF` function returns an `INT` so it will not work as you like, your best bet is to subtract InTime from OutTime or use `DATEDIFF` with minutes (`n`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. you should probably do UI formatting on the client, not the database
2. you can use diff = datediff(mi, intime, outtime) to get the difference in minutes

then divide diff by 60 to get the hours

and take the modulus diff % 60 to get the remaining minutes

then turn into strings and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Outime - InTime as Diff_time from EmpLogTable
```

DATEDIFF measures day, hour etc boundaries: you're asking for a true date/time difference. In this case, I'd simply subtract the values rather than using a complex nested DATEDIFF. Or do it in the client.

If you have a interval > 24 hours though, then you'd need a nested DATEDIFF to get 25 hours: my answer would give one day and one hour.

The hh:nn:ss format can be done via [CONVERT with style 108](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), but again I'd do this in the client

Comment: That is not correct.

datediff(mi, '2010-07-25 12:00:00', '2009-07-25 12:00:00') = -525600

Comment: @el chief: subtraction is not the same as DATEDIFF. What are you trying to say?